# converting between types in javascript

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I need to write a function that returns the last element from the input arguments. This is easy for Strings and Arrays, but the function can also accept a "list of arguments". I have tried to process this list of arguments with String and Array syntax, but I get errors about object not having method x. This is what I have so far:

```
function last(list){
  // return last element of array
  if(list instanceof Array){
    return list[list.length-1];
  }
  // return last element of string
  else if(typeof list === 'string'){
    return list.substring(list.length-1, list.length);
  }
}
```

Is there a way to convert an arbitrary list of arguments to a String or Array? Here is an example of what I mean by list of arguments.

```
Test.assertEquals(last(1,"b",3,"d",5), 5);
```

Comment: can you give an example of what is giving you the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the "arguments" object.  So something like

```
function last(list) {
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
        return arguments[arguments.length-1];
    }
    else {
       ... (as now)
 }
```

Comment: if the argument is a single array, will arguments[arguments.length-1] return the last value of the array or a reference to the array?

Comment: if the argument itself is [1, 2, 3], arguments[arguments.length-1] will return [1, 2, 3], not the values inside

Answer (score 1):

You can just call arguments[arguments.length -1] inside the function, and it should give you the last argument, regardless of type.

Here's the resource on arguments: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments